# Python - is there a way to store an operation(+ - * /) in a list or as a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The reason I ask is pure curiosity. I could see, possibly, that this might be useful if you didn't know ahead of time what operations you wanted to apply to certain variables, or to apply a different operation during a certain level in a recursive call, or perhaps it may just make certain things easier and/or neater.

Though am just speculating, it could be a really bad idea, but overall am just curious.

Comment: Check out [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#module-operator) module.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#module-operator) module.

> The `operator` module exports a set of efficient functions
>   corresponding to the intrinsic operators of Python. For example,
>   `operator.add(x, y)` is equivalent to the expression `x+y`. The function
>   names are those used for special class methods; variants without
>   leading and trailing __ are also provided for convenience.

So storing "operation" in list is as simple as:

```
import operator
operations = [operator.add, operator.sub]
# add two numbers
s = operations[0](1, 2)
```

Comment: Yeah that pretty much nails it :)

Comment: And if an operator you want isn't in the module, just wrap it in a function; named or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put functions in a list, or a dict (which can be quite useful), you can do it with functions declared with def, lambdas or import already defined functions, from operators module with your examples (operator.add, etc)